# Delta values different after saving multi-value field with user_save

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

My module loops through a users current groups they belong to (Organic Group), adds them to an array, then after that loop completes, the new group is added and the array is saved to the user via `user_save()`. It's working, but the delta values are coming back different. It seems to be adding on to this value every time I save a user this way. For example:

```
$data = array();               //array to hold groups
$i = 0;
foreach($user->og_user_node['und'] as $oldgroup)
{
     $data['og_user_node']['und'][$i]['target_id'] = $oldgroup['target_id'];
     dpm($data);
     dpm($i);
     $i++;
}
$data['og_user_node']['und'][$i]['target_id'] = $groupid;
dpm($data);               // This is correct, deltas are 0,1,2.. etc... 
$newuser = user_save($user, $data);
dpm($newuser);            // This comes back with Deltas like 323,324,327 sometimes it skips numbers even within the same save and even if there are only 1 or 2 groups in this field.
```

It seems to have started at 320 and it's working it's way up every time new groups are added to the user. If it was incrementing from my testing, I've only added this user to maybe 10-11 groups, so I can't imagine where this value is coming from.

Like I said, this is correctly adding the user to the new group and keeping their old memberships, I just worry this may cause an issue somewhere else now having 'correct' Delta values.